# How to get routeUrl of Custom route value in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

This question will be two questions

I have changed the values of my routes using the `@page` directive via [Microsoft's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#custom-routes) documentation. As an example I have changed one of my routes with the filename `Landing.cshtml` to `@page "/"`. Now I am trying to get the value of the new custom route that I have defined as I would like to send the user back to that page pending direction from my signup logic like so:

```
returnUrl = Request.Form["returnUrl"];
```

Then

```
return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
```

I am passing in the returnUrl from a from that is posting to this PageModel via the below input

```
<input type="hidden" id="returnUrl" name="returnUrl" value='@((string) ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Page"])' />
```

Yet the value always is the defaul `/Landing` and not the custom value I defined on the page of `/`.

**Question 1:** How do you go about sending in the custom page url without hard coding it into the form value itself

**Question 2:** What is the difference between `ViewContext.RouteData.Values` and `RouteData.Values`, they both have the same keys and values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question1**

You can get the Name of the Route like this:

```
// it only returns the name, so you have to add the "/"
var routeName = "/" + ViewContext.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo.Template;

// @page "/" --> ""
// @page "/foobar" --> "foobar"
```

**Question 2**

I am not sure but i think there is no difference. It is the same type of object. *ViewContext.RouteData* are the Values for the Request and *RouteData* alone is mentioned as Values for the Action according to Intellisense.

Comment: This works, thank you for the answer. I am not sure how I would have figured that out as any google searches turn up nothing.